# UITableViewCell subclass, how to draw buttons?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm making an app that needs three buttons in each tableview cell. I tried just adding the buttons to the cell using `addSubview` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` but this resulted in slow/janky scrolling with more than 6 or 7 rows.

I did some research online and have followed Apple's example of subclassing the UITableViewCell and drawing everything in `drawRect`. I can get text and images to draw perfectly, using `drawAtPoint` but this doesn't appear to work for UIButtons.

Adding the button as a subview of `[self contentView]` (in my subclasses `drawRect`) just results in even worse scroll lag than before.

Does anyone know how to get a button to draw properly within my UITableViewCell subclass?

Getting this right is crucial to the entire app so any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: Here is the code used for for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

AHCustomCell * cell = (AHCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    AHCustomCell * customCell = [[[AHCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    customCell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 55.0);
    cell = customCell;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method? If you're either not recycling or if you're doing lots of work in either tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: or tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: then you may well get 'janky' scrolling.

Comment: I tried recycling the cell using an identifier but during scrolling the label text in several cells kept changing randomly. Do I need to reuse the cell if I've subclassed it? Apple didn't seem to do this in the CustomTableViewCell sample code I downloaded.

Comment: OK, so looking at the code in your post you are recycling. (By the way, in your code, you set the cell height in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath. That isn't going to do anything. The cell height is set by tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:.) But where are you creating your buttons? If you are creating them in outside of the your if block but inside tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: then, stop doing that and either override initWithStyle: in AHCustomCell and creating them there, or create them inside the if block in the code you have posted.

Comment: I actually create the buttons and label in the `drawRect` method of my AHCustomCellView class, and then add that to the AHCustomCell subclass. This is how Apple does it in their TableViewSuite. Are you saying this is wrong?

Comment: Not sure I would say it was wrong. It sounds like a lot of effort and it doesn't seem to be working for you. I've posted an answer that gives three buttons with no jaggy-ness. I've tested it on a table with 50 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code gives three buttons and no jaggy scrolling. Using tags, you can reset the text of the buttons depending on the row. This is illustrated for button 1 (which adjusts its title according to the row number). The `button1Pressed:` method illustrated figures out what row the button press came from. Hope this will be helpful.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // see if there's a cell available to recylce
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        // there's no cell to recycle, so make a new one
        // add three buttons to it and tag them so we can alter their contents later

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        UIButton* button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button1 setTitle:@"Button 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(4.0, 15.0, 110, 30.0)];
        [button1 setTag:101];
        [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1Pressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:button1];

        UIButton* button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button2 setTitle:@"Button 2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(120.0, 15.0, 80.0, 30.0)];
        [button2 setTag:102];
        [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button2Pressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:button2];

        UIButton* button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button3 setTitle:@"Button 3" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button3 setFrame:CGRectMake(210, 15.0, 80.0, 30.0)];
        [button3 setTag:103];
        [button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(button3Pressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:button3];

    }

    // either on a recycled cell or on the cell just created, set the contents

    UIButton* button1 = (UIButton*)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:101];
    [button1 setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button 1 - %d", [indexPath row]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}



- (void) button1Pressed: (UIButton*) button
{
   CGPoint buttonCentre = [button convertPoint:[button center] toView:[self tableView]];

    NSLog(@"Button 1 Pressed on row %d", [[[self tableView] indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonCentre] row]);
}
```

Comment: I have uses your sample code and the more cells that are in the table view, the worse the scrolling performance becomes.

Comment: Puzzling I just checked my code again - running on a device,  not simulator - with 200 rows. No scrolling performance issues at all. And, given the way the code / Apple's design works, it should not matter how many rows there are. The only time a method is called for EVERY row is when you do a reloadData. If your scrolling performance is related to the number of rows in the table, it sounds as if you are doing some extra work in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: that is affected by the number of rows. To get more help (from me or anyone else) I suspect you'll have to post a bit more code.

Comment: I am also testing on a device, though it is a 3rd gen iPod touch. Would this make much difference?

Comment: No. Your test device is not the issue - that's also my test device. Something odd is up here. When the oddness gets too much, I often find the best strategy is to create a small scratch project. In your case, you could build up from a simple UITableViewController and keep adding bits in from your real project. At some point whatever is causing the issue will become apparent.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the `UITableViewCell`s are the same format, just with different information, I would suggest making a subclass of `UITableViewCell` which knows how to format the cell with some kind of Model object, and hooked up to it's own `nib`. That way, you can load up the new cell easily in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, and it should speed up your app significantly. It's also much easier to make changes to the custom cells, and is easier to implement. There are tons of tutorials online about how to do this. [Here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/) is one I just found on google. Hope that helps!

Comment: Initially, this was exactly how I was doing it. A custom cell nib with  a label and the three buttons. But it was painfully slow while scrolling, visibly jumping as each cell was loaded. Thats why I looked at subclassing UITableViewCell. I now have a custom UITableViewCell subclass, which in turn has a UIView in it with the buttons (exactly how apple does it). But, its still not smooth scrolling.

Comment: How large are your cells? Is there a lot of content being loaded into them?

Comment: 320 x 55, and the only content in them is a label and the three buttons.

Comment: Can you post your code for your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method? Are you using `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]`?

Comment: The code gets pasted wrong, is there a better place to show you?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really draw an UIButton in `-drawRect:`, unless you really create a button from scratch (i.e. without using the UIButton class). You can however change the frame of an UIButton in `-drawRect`. You might need to call `-setNeedsDisplay` inside your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to force `drawRect:` to be executed.

The code for the UITableViewCell subclass could look like the following:

```
@synthesize button = _button;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
   self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
   if (self) 
   {         
      _button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
      [self.contentView addSubview:_button];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [_button release];
    [super dealloc];    
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame
{   
    _button.frame = CGRectMake(20.0f, 5.0f, 100.0f, 30.0f);
}
```